# How to autowire a spring bean based on some session info

Tags: java, spring, autowired

We are working on a multilingual Spring based web application (not Spring Boot).

Now we are searching for the "spring way" of doing the following.

1. user starts a http session with some parameters, e.g. a locale "de" and/or a country-code "DE" (the type of parameter isn't really important)
2. user works with application
3. at some point the user triggers an action that somewhere deep inside needs a "localized" functionality

Example (java pseudocode):

```java
// service with functionality common for all users
@Service
class CommonService implements ICommonService
{
    // how to autowire a service based on some info in the actual HttpSession, eg. CustomServiceUK or CustomServiceDE
    @Autowired
    private ICustomService customServiceImpl;

    @Override
    public void doSomeAction(String param)
    {
        ... do some common stuff

        customResult = customServiceImpl.calculate(param);

        ... do some common stuff with custom result
    }
}

// custom service implementations
@Service("CustomServiceUK")
class CustomServiceUK implements ICustomService
{
    @Override
    public String calculate(String value)
    {
        ... execute logic on value for an "uk" user
    }
}

@Service("CustomServiceDE")
class CustomServiceDE implements ICustomService
{
    @Override
    public String calculate(String value)
    {
        ... execute logic on value for an "de" user
    }
}
```

How to inject a custom service based on some info in the actual HttpSession (e.g. CustomServiceUK or CustomServiceDE) into CommonService?
What are our options to solve this issue? Is there something like a dynamic @Qualifier or some @Autowired Spring-Factory thing?

(the service implementation to use must not necessarily depend on the locale of the user but on some other piece of session/request information)

Comment: Did you take a look on Session scope https://tuhrig.de/making-a-spring-bean-session-scoped/

Comment: I don't think there's any way to dynamically supplier the qualifier value. One possible alternative can be to write an interceptor, use the session information and application context to create the required instance ICustomService and set it in your CommonService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

Actually we end up with the following solution which works for us.

We created an additional implementation of ICustomService with name CustomServiceProxy.
This service has @Primary annotation to tell Spring that this component should be injected when no explicit qualifier is supplied.
The service gets the sessionData and a Map with all Spring managed ICustomService-Components injected (Map-Key = Qualifier of the Component).
Now when some method on CustomServiceProxy gets called, it generates the Map-Key based on the actual sessionData (e.g. language), lookup the ICustomService in the Map and delegates the call to this specific service.

```java
// service with functionality common for all users
@Service
class CommonService implements ICommonService
{
    // because of @Primary an instance of CustomServiceProxy will be injected
    @Autowired
    private ICustomService customServiceImpl;

    @Override
    public void doSomeAction(String param)
    {
        ... do some common stuff

        customResult = customServiceImpl.calculate(param);

        ... do some common stuff with custom result
    }
}

// custom service implementations
@Service
@Primary
class CustomServiceProxy implements ICustomService
{
    private CustomData sessionData;
    private Map<String, ICustomService> services;

    @Autowired
    public CustomServiceProxy(CustomData sessionData, Map<String, ICustomService> services)
    {
        this.sessionData = sessionData;
        this.services = services;
    }

    @Override
    public String calculate(String value)
    {
        String serviceName = "CustomService" + sessionData.getLanguage().toUpperCase();
        ICustomService customService = services.get(serviceName);
        // handle missing service: throw exception or maybe switch to a default implementation
        Objects.requireNonNull(customService, "missing CustomService with name " + serviceName);
        return customService.calculate(value);
    }
}

@Service("CustomServiceUK")
class CustomServiceUK implements ICustomService
{
    @Override
    public String calculate(String value)
    {
        ... execute logic on value for an "uk" user
    }
}

@Service("CustomServiceDE")
class CustomServiceDE implements ICustomService
{
    @Override
    public String calculate(String value)
    {
        ... execute logic on value for an "de" user
    }
}
```

Comment: Going and looking into the map based on the key, an elegant solution. Not the most suitable one but nonetheless an preferable.